# \newcommand and CSV file

Tags: macros, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like this

```
testa, 123
testb, 456
testc, 789
```

How can process the CSV file to get the following result?

```
\newcommand{\testa}{123}
\newcommand{\testb}{456}
\newcommand{\testc}{789}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newread\zz
\def\xpar{\par}
\def\zzdef#1,#2#3 \relax{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2#3}}
\openin\zz=zz.csv
\loop
\ifeof\zz
\else
\read\zz to \tmp
\ifx\tmp\xpar\else
\expandafter\zzdef\tmp\relax
\fi
\repeat
\begin{document}


 testa is [\testa]

 testb is [\testb]

 testc is [\testc]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can process each line of the CSV using [`datatool`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)'s `\DTLforeach` processor and create a macro for each:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
testa, 123
testb, 456
testc, 789
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={varname,datavalue}]{data}{data.csv}
\DTLforeach{data}{\varname=varname,\datavalue=datavalue}{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\varname\endcsname{\datavalue}%
}

\verb|\testa|: \testa

\verb|\testb|: \testb

\verb|\testc|: \testc

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\edef\csname\varname\endcsname{\datavalue}` is sufficient. Or `\expandafter\def\csname\varname\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\datavalue}` (safer).

Answer (score 4):

With `expl3`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
testa, 123
testb, 456
testc, 789
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definefromcsv}{m}
 {
  \schneider_definefromcsv:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \schneider_definefromcsv:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
   {
    \__schneider_define:n { ##1 }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__schneider_define:n
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \cs_new:cpx { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 } }
   {
    \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definefromcsv{\jobname.csv}

\verb|\testa|: --\testa--

\verb|\testb|: --\testb--

\verb|\testc|: --\testc--

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes. With `\ior_map_inline:Nn` the trailing space is not removed, but `\clist_set:Nn` takes care of that, because it strips leading and trailing spaces around items when it normalizes the clist. The presence of “`\edef` dangerous” macros such as `\textbf` is not a problem, because `\clist_item:Nn` returns the item in “unexpandable form”, that is, surrounded by `\exp_not:n` (`\unexpanded` in eTeX lingo).

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness, a LuaTeX solution. Assuming you have the (name, definition) pairs in a file called `foo.csv`, put the following in a file called say `define.lua`:

```lua
for line in io.lines("foo.csv") do
   name, def = line:match("([^,]+), ([^,]+)")
   token.set_macro(name, def)
end
```

Then you can compile the below with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile('define.lua')}
\begin{document}
Here we can say \testa, \testb, and \testc.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly more intuitive version of Werner's answer (or David's) using  `datatool` and `etoolbox`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
testa, 123
testb, 456
testc, 789
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={name,value}]{csnames}{\jobname.csv}
\DTLforeach*{csnames}{\myname=name,\myvalue=value}{
\csxdef{\myname}{\expandonce{\myvalue}}
}
\verb|\testa|: \testa

\verb|\testb|: \testb

\verb|\testc|: \testc
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What if the first line is `testa,\textbf{123}`? `;-)` Better doing`\csxdef{\myname}{\expandonce{\myvalue}}`